# VisualStudioコードスニペットをコメントの中で起動したい

Tags: visual-studio

VisualStudio2015を使用しています。
定形的なコメントの挿入を楽にするために、以下のようなスニペットを作成しました。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>delete argument</Title>
      <Shortcut>delargs</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="CPP" Kind="any">
        ここに渡すポインタは呼び出し側でdeleteしないでください。
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

[コード スニペット スキーマ リファレンス](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms171418.aspx#code)では、
Kindで使用出来る any について

> スニペットをどこにでも挿入できることを示します。 このタグは、コメントなど、コンテキストに依存しないコード スニペットに使用します。

と記述してあるのですが、Ctrl+SpaceもしくはCtrl+K, Ctrl+X を使用しても
コメントの中ではポップアップメニューを表示させることが出来ません。
(それ以外の箇所ではポップアップ表示されることを確認済み)

これは何か記述の方法が間違っているのでしょうか？